# Using short signs instead of words

Tags: ruby

I noticed a way of writing to a text file, i.e.,

```
file >> "TEXT"
```

It works the same as:

```
file.puts "TEXT"
file.print "TEXT"
```

1. Is it safe to use such signs in a large script?
2. Please list all such short signs or give a website that lists all those signs.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2):

1. Of course.
2. This is simply a regular method on `File` objects (with a bit of syntaxic sugar so you don't have to use a `.` to call it). It's the same idea as adding numbers: `1 + 2` is actually the same as `1.+(2)`.

   However, I'm pretty sure you've made a typo in your code. It's `<<`, not `>>`.

   You can find a list of "short signs" (i.e. methods) in [the Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Comment: The generally used term for these "short signs" is *operator*. This is the term that will yield better responses when searching.